# Сочетание "слабо морозный" в предложении "выходные в Екатеринбурге будут слабо морозными и без снега"

Tags: стилистика, орфография, раздельно-дефис

> [Выходные в Екатеринбурге будут **слабо морозными** и без снега](http://www.e1.ru/news/spool/news_id-438046.html)

Заголовок новости на нашем местном портале. Как-то зацепило словосочетание "слабо морозными". Как оно с точки зрения грамматики и стилистики?

Может быть, правильнее писать через дефис? Нашел у Солженицына:

> Стоял красный солнечный денёк – ещё **слабо-морозный**, но и в свете и в воздухе уже была весна. На домах висели красные флаги. Много гуляющих. Станкевич прошёл проулком на Фурштадтскую и дальше по узкому её бульвару. Уже близ Потёмкинской встретил Колю, своего троюродного племянника, гимназиста выпускного класса.

Можно ли в этом новостном заголовке писать "слабо морозный" раздельно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сочетания "слабо морозная погода", "слабо морозная ночь" скорее относятся к погодным терминам,  в словарях сложного слова(со слитным написанием слабоморозная ночь ) нет, хотя по логике оно возможно.

С точки зрения грамматики "слабо" может быть и частью сложного слова и писаться слитно, и обозначать оттенок чего-то и писаться через дефис,и отдельным наречием меры и степени, как   наречие "умеренно"(умеренно жаркий, умеренно морозный, умеренно мягкий). Если вспомнить климатическую терминологию,по температурным условиям погоду разделяют на три типа: безморозная, с переходом температуры через 0 ° С и морозная , а вот морозная бывает в какой степени? - очень  морозная, умеренно морозная, слабо морозная.

Так что в этом смысле вполне корректно писать на погодных сайтах "слабо морозная погода", "слабо морозная ночь"и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь, конечно, пишется слитно: "слабоморозные" – от "слабые морозы". Сравните: "железнодорожный" – от "железная дорога"

Answer (score 1):

Начало следующей недели, по прогнозам синоптиков, также будет слабо морозным.

Это выражение часто используется в прогнозах и пишется обычно раздельно: наречие + прилагательное. Имеется в виду не слабые морозы, а слегка морозная погода.

Вариант "слабо-морозный денек" - авторский, по аналогии с оттенками значений (бледно-голубой, приторно-сладкий).